# I am getting an error when inserting with execute($array)

Tags: php, arrays, pdo, insert

I have a table

```
percentile      int(3)  No           
FoSW            int(3)  Yes     NULL     
dfLR            int(3)  Yes     NULL     
FoA             int(3)  Yes     NULL     
SoG             int(3)  Yes     NULL     
RST             int(3)  Yes     NULL     
SSW             int(3)  Yes     NULL    
total           int(3)  No
```

and an array:

```
Array
(
    [percentile] => 99
    [FoSW] => 125
    [DfLR] => 110
    [FoA] => 60
    [SoG] => 120
    [RST] => 40
    [SSW] => 45
    [total] => 500
)
```

And this code that does not work for some reason... Catch does not throw an error. Just my if statement which echos error...

```
if ($_POST['percent']=='add'){
    try{
        $post = $_POST;
        unset($post['percent']);

        $sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO percentiles (percentile, FoSW, dfLR, FoA, SoG, RST, SSW, total) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

        if ($sth->execute($post)){
            echo 'done<br/>';
        }

        else echo 'error';
    }

    catch(PDOException $e){
        echo 'error'.$e;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're effectively assigning $_POST to your placeholders - are there 8 fields in $_POST? Are they in the eight order?

Comment: yes, as you can see in the array i showed there are 8 items in the array and in the right order. I unset the one item that should not be there.

Comment: The [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) on PDOStatement->Execute doesn't say that it throws an exception.  Are you certain that it **should** be?

Comment: no i am not certain that it should throw an exception, but it is not inserting and I can not figure out why.

Comment: Also, there is no auto_incremented key.. could that be it?

Comment: @SmithSmithy - I can see an associative array, that has 8 key-value pairs. That's 16 elements. You might be wanting to get just the values of $_POST; but it'll be a lot easier to maintain if you explicitly assign values. If you change your form in the future, this code will break - even if you move a couple of fields around.

Comment: try `$sth->errorcode()` and `$sth->errorInfo()`. They will contain error information when execute returns false. Execute doesn't throw an exception.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/a/15990858/689579 about getting PDO error messages.

Comment: @andrewsi can you show me what to do with the $post array to correct. I understand what you are saying about maintaining the code, but I still want to see this script work.

Comment: @SmithSmithy - you can get away with `$sth->execute(array($_POST['percentile], $_POST['FoSW'].....`, explicitly naming each $_POST field in the execute.

Comment: ok so no way to execute($array)???

Comment: If you have php>=5.2 No - from http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php `Changelog :: The keys from input_parameters must match the ones declared in the SQL. Before PHP 5.2.0 this was silently ignored.`

Comment: @sean so i need to convert it to an indexed array and throw away the keys correct?

Comment: either an un-indexed array, or need to use `$sth->bindParam()` if wanting to index. see example #3 & #4 - http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array `$post` matches the eight values required for `INSERT` operation, but the array should be indexed by integers and not associative array/dictionary.

```
Array
(
    [percentile] => 99
    [FoSW] => 125
    [DfLR] => 110
    [FoA] => 60
    [SoG] => 120
    [RST] => 40
    [SSW] => 45
    [total] => 500
)
```

The above array will work if you change your `prepare()` call as follows:

```php
$sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO percentiles 
        (percentile, FoSW, 
        dfLR, FoA, 
        SoG, RST, 
        SSW, total) 
    VALUES
        (:percentile, :FoSW, 
        :DfLR, :FoA, 
        :SoG, :RST, 
        :SSW, :total)");
```